# Reading text file line by line in NetBeans

Tags: java

I'm using the following code to read from a file

```
int lineNumber = 0;
  try{
       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("electric.txt"));
  String line = null;
    while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
     lineNumber++;
     system.out.println("Line "+ lineNumber + " : "+ line);
     }
   } catch(IOException e){
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

My file have specific values on each line, for exemple first line is int, second string, third boolean etc...

My question is how do I get each data type in a variable?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, in a naive approach, you just do as many reads as you need:

```
String firstLine = in.readLine();
String secondLine = in.readLine();
...
```

Then you could do something like:

```
Whatever dataObject = new Whatever(firstLine, secondLine, ...);
```

for example (maybe within a loop, as you probably want to read the data for many data objects, not just a single one).

In other words: you read the required attributes in some helper variables, to then push those into the object you want to fill with data. Advantage: this works for very large data, as you only read a few lines at a time. Downside: you have to worry about invalid files, missing lines, and such things (so you need quite a bit of error handling).

Alternatively: simply read the whole file into memory first, for example using `List<String> allLines = java.util.Files.readAllLines(somePathToYourFile);` Then, you iterate these `allLines` an further process your content, now without worrying about IOExceptions for example.

Comment: I can't seem to find out how get your alternate method in a loop to get my variables...

Comment: The alternate method reads all content into memory in one shot. Afterwards you iterate over that list of lines and process / use them in any way you want to.

Comment: So my app should show specification of laptops.I have a class Laptop(processor[String],RAM[int],Windows[boolean]..etc) and I need to take these arguments from a file, btw im kinda newbie so eh...

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Converting strings? Creating new objects? Please be as specific as possible, and please: add all that information to your question, instead of putting them into comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether the line is boolean, integer, or String, this is a possible solution. If you need to check that the line is long or short, double or float, etc. You still have to handle those cases.

System.out.println("Line " + lineNumber + " : " + line + ", Datatype: " + typeChecker(line));

```
public static String typeChecker(String line){
    if (line.equals("true")||line.equals("false"))
    return "boolean";
    else{ if (isInteger(line))
        return "int";
    }
    return "String";
}

public static boolean isInteger(String s) {
    try { 
       Integer.parseInt(s); 
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) { 
       return false; 
    } catch(NullPointerException e) {
       return false;
    }
return true;
}
```